# Unable to retrieve session variables in PHP when using header("Location:

Tags: php, header, session-variables

Once user provides username and password on Login page, it is then submitted to another page which has -

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username']=$_POST["username"];
```

Based on some validation, the page is redirected to different pages based on the code below

```
session_write_close();
/* Redirect browser */
header("Location: ../menu.php");
```

Then, on menu.php, all I tried to do is -

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo "User is ".$_SESSION['username']; 
?>
```

But its not working :(. Works on the same page though but not after redirection. Tried with setcookie etc but no luck. Appreciate any help !!

Comment: Get rid of `session_write_close();`

Comment: Does not work does not qualify as a question.

Comment: @ j08691, tried without session_write_close() but that didnt work
@hakre, why doesnt it qualify for a question?

Comment: Because you have not specified how it looks like when it does not work, You have not told what it means when it works, and you have not told why you think it *should* work. This calls for basic debugging first - Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your scripts. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: i have already tried basic debugging from my end. If I could have resolved it, wouldnt have put it here. In logs I see,

PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  username

But again, if I check and echo the value of $_SESSION['username']; on the same page it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your header location i think you are redirecting to a parent folder. This will screw up your sessions if you do not define your cookie path and domain.
This can be achieved with the function: [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: it wasnt allowing me to put the url, hence had to put ... But its the same folder.